# Postgres handle constraint conflict then insert excluded row

Tags: postgresql

If I have a table something like:

```
MyTable
id    date           value    replaced_by_id
1     2020-01-01      10        
2     2020-01-02      20        3
3     2020-01-02      21
```

With a unique constraint on date and replaced_by
e.g.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_table_null_test ON my_table (date, (replaced_by_id is null))
WHERE replaced_by_id IS NULL;
```

How can I create an insert statement that sets the conflicting row's replaced_by_id to the the new rows id and then inserts the new row afterwards?

Along the lines of

```
insert into my_table (id, date, value) values (gen_id(), '2020-01-02', 21)
on conflict (date, (replaced_by_id is null) ) where replaced_by_id is null 
do update
set replaced_by_id = excluded.id 

**now insert the new row (insert the excluded row)**
```

for say the file the values are coming from a file that had many values for the same date.  e.g.

```
   date           value
   2020-01-01      10        
   2020-01-02      20     
   2020-01-02      21        
   2020-01-02      22    
   2020-01-02      23    
   2020-01-02      24    
   2020-01-02      22
```

would result in

```
MyTable
id    date           value    replaced_by_id
1     2020-01-01      10        
2     2020-01-02      20        3
3     2020-01-02      21        4
4     2020-01-02      22        5
5     2020-01-02      23        6
6     2020-01-02      24        7
7     2020-01-02      22
```

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally wrong. as you are trying to update the replace_by_id field first and then insert the new row. But basic question is how you will get the new ID before insert?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not use `UPSERT` for this requirement because `UPSERT` will perform only update operation on same table or `DO Nothing`.

Reason is:

1. You have added `unique index` which will prevent the insertion with combination of existing date and null of `replace_by_id` field.
2. You are trying to get the ID to update the existing records before insertion which is not possible.

So you have to use some workaround for it:

**Using Triggers** - You have to use `2 triggers` on your table one is before insert and one is after insert like below:

**Before Insert Trigger**

Trigger Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION trig_beforeinsert()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
declare 
flg int :=0;
begin
flg=(select count(*) from my_table where date_=new.date_ and replaced_by_id is null);

if flg>0 then
new.replaced_by_id=0;
end if;
return new;
end;

$BODY$;
```

Trigger on Table

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_before_insert
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON my_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trig_beforeinsert();
```

**After Insert Trigger**

Trigger Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION trig_afterinsert()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
declare 
flg int :=0;
begin

if new.replaced_by_id = 0 then
UPDATE my_table set replaced_by_id=new.id where date_=new.date_ and replaced_by_id is null;
UPDATE my_table set replaced_by_id=null where id=new.id;
end if;
return new;
end;

$BODY$;
```

Trigger on Table

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_after_insert
    AFTER INSERT
    ON public.my_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.trig_afterinsert();
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=99cef676573f980ebbd092e226126f67)